How to solve verification lbank API failed and use server timestamp in requests?
I'm trying use lbank API:

I set API and secret key

when I use API to get public data ( historical price of trading pairs , timstamp ...) it truly works.

but when I want to use authorized actions (create order、cancel order ...) I get verification failed.
I'm using python library that lbak developed here.

I check the code and library and API documentation:

API documentation  denotes

timestamp: millisecond of current time (1567833674095). It's strongly recommended that you get it from /v2/timestamp.do<


and in library timestamp generates based on system's time for use in request's header
def get_timestamp() -> str:
return str(int(time.time() * 1000)).split(".", maxsplit=1)[0]

and I think that is verification failed reason is the difference between timestamps in request's header and server time stamp

does it the reason of failed?

how can I fix this error?


This is my code:
async def mytrade():

res=await trade.trade_test_create_order('btc_usdt','buy_market',price=59000,amount=1,custom_id='btcbuy')
    
res=trade.http_request('get','/v2/timestamp.do')
res = await trade.get_user_info()
print(res,trade.timestamp)'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
api_key = "*******************************"
api_secret = "**************************"
# service address
base_url = "https://api.lbkex.com/"
# Encryption method
sign_method = "HmacSHA256"
trade=Spot(sign_method=sign_method,
    api_key=api_key,
    api_secret=api_secret,
    base_url=base_url,)

asyncio.run(mytrade())

